# Automatically rerun jobs submitted with sbatch --array upon error

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I am submitting jobs in an array. Occasionally one job will error because of a difficult to diagnose gpu memory issue. Simply rerunning the job results in success.

What I would like to do is catch this error, log it, and put the job back into slurm's queue to be rerun. If this is not possible to do with an array job, that's fine, it's not essential to use arrays (though it is preferred).

I've tried playing around with sbatch --rerun, but this doesn't seem to do what I want (I think this option is for rerunning after a hardware error detected by slurm, or a node is restarted when a job is running - this isn't the case for my jobs).

Any advice well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can detect the GPU memory issue, you can end your submission job with a construct like this:

```
if <gpu memory issue>; then
    scontrol requeue $SLURM_JOBID
fi
```

This will put the job back in the scheduling queue and it will be restarted as is. Interestingly, the `SLURM_RESTART_COUNT` environment variable holds the number of times the job was re-queued.

Comment: Excellent - I'll give this a shot and flesh this answer out later. More specifically, I'll need to catch an error within python, and pass it back out to the bash script submitted to slurm.

The `SLURM_RESTART_COUNT` variable will be very useful - if it gets too high it'll be worth bailing entirely - likely big hardware failure or (more likely) user error!